# Firefox can not allow permanent access to your screen

Tags: firefox

I can't share my screen(present) in google meet. I tried adding "full-screen-api.approval-required " in about:config and set its value to **true** . II restarted firefox after that and tried to present/share my screen but the option still remains greyed out and firefox is displaying "Firefox can not allow permanent access to your screen". I am running Win 10 and everything is updated. [Here's the image link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XmCS.png) . I tried selecting every option such as "share whole screen" and all but still no avail.

Answer (score -2):

Please uncheck  "Remember this decision"  -   that should solve the problem ....

Comment: Apparently i am able to share my screen now but the audio isnt coming even though speaker permissions are there. That was a new problem, I didnt do anything. It was fine until then and suddenly one day it just stopped outputting sounds. Had to use chrome everytime for attending G meets